# Prometheus Grafana Query that gives total of api 200 success once every 24 hours

Tags: prometheus, grafana-alerts, kube-prometheus-stack

i'm trying to trigger an alert once every 24 hours at specific time.  Trying to get the count of how many times 200 success happened within past 24 hour time frame

```
sum(increase(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_count{namespace=~"prod", destination_workload=~"x-service-*.*", reporter="destination", response_code=~"[2].."}[24h]))
```

but this is doing concurrent 24 hours and not from yesterday 9am to today 9am type scenario.

Anyone know how to do query for once every 24 hours?  I'm not sure if my query is even right.  New to this.